# Need to correct this complex grid/table layout using twitter/bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a complex layout using table in twitter-bootstrap. However, I'm not able to get it perfectly right! Particularly, where 5 is displayed!

Is it possible to achieve the same using div's instead? How would I get the borders in that case? 
Please check the design attached.

[image]

```
<div class="container">
            <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:80%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-6" colspan="4"><strong>1</strong></td>
                    <td class="col-md-4" rowspan="3"><img src="#" /></td>
                    <td class="col-md-2" rowspan="3"><button class="del-icon">X</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-3"><strong>2</strong></td>
                    <td class="col-md-3"><strong>3</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>4</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>5</strong></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you just add row to 2,3 then another row for 4,5

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 blue1">
  1
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 blue2">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 blue3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 blue4">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-10 blue5">5</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 blue6">
 img
</div>
 <div class="col-md-2 blue7">
 x
</div>
```

Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/mraM3WKCvt

Hope that helps, cheerio!